# Automation Anywhere. How do I pick a value from dropdown

Tags: automation, automationanywhere

Automation Anywhere. How do I pick a value from dropdown. I tried 'set text' from a copied variable. Its very slow, and also doesnt seem to be the right away. I would want to pick a value from the dropdown. Any idea how this can be done ? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Object Cloning** for this.

The process will be like:

1. Select object cloning and select the window you want to clone.
2. Capture the object to which you want to select from the drop-down.
3. Object cloning intelligence will automatically treat this as Drop down, and an extra option like "select Item by text" will appear in the action list. Select that option.
4. It will only suggest the all the drop down options. Select the required option you want.
5. Press Save.

That's it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using '**Manage Windows Controls**' AA Command ( in this command make sure you check available checkbox for Capture a control of specific type [select -  **Drop Down**] in next text box) and  capture the value from pick list.